# CoffeeScript | Unexpected newline (translated to java, looks fine)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am writing some code for Framer which uses CoffeeScript. I'm new to CoffeeScript but have experience in Java and Python.

I wrote some code and tried to run, got an unexpected newline error. To understand this better, I put my code into [coffeelint.org](http://www.coffeelint.org) and got the same error.

So I tried sectioning the code off but it's still giving the error, I've had two other people look over it and they can't find the error:

```
for data in roomData:
  if data == londonData
    name = 'London'
  else if data == seattleData
    name = 'Seattle'
  else if data == downtownData
    name = 'Down Town'
  else
    name = 'Toyko'

  Card = new Layer
```

The 'Card = new Layer' has to be defined in the for loop. Translated this into JS using [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee) and also getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added unnecessary colon. Should be

```
for data in roomData # no :
  if data == londonData
    name = 'London'
  else if data == seattleData
    name = 'Seattle'
  else if data == downtownData
    name = 'Down Town'
  else
    name = 'Toyko'

  Card = new Layer
```

BTW instead of multiple if-else with assignments you could use switch

```
for data in roomData
  name = switch data
    when londonData then 'London'
    when seattleData then 'Seattle'
    when downtownData then 'Down Town'
    else 'Tokio'

  Card = new Layer
```

Comment: ha beat me to it, nice one

Comment: Holy damn, the three of us back here are laughing, thanks dude!

Comment: @SylentNyte you should accept and upvote this answer mate

Comment: @Ursus my apologies, i forgot